# Website viewed on phone does not display updates

Tags: wordpress, mobile, mobile-website, real-time-updates, divi-theme

I'm building a website using WordPress with Divi Theme. I try to make specific settings for the phone view of the web page and every time, when I change something (I change the size, I add text or image, I create a new post/page. I save and publish) I can not see the updates on the site when I open the website on the phone. Why? And What can I do to solve this?

Thank you!

I cleaned data cached and I add a plugin AMP – Accelerated Mobile Pages but I didn't see any result, maybe I didn't know how to use it.
I want to be able to see the updates immediately for visitors and also for me when I make changes to know if they look good on the phone view.

Answer (score 0):

If you already clean the Cache then here is a check list -

1. you can change the internet then check
2. and first you can check your changes in inspect.
3. before publishing the changes ensures that the changes are correctly
   applied to the mobile version of your website.
4. Double-check that the changes you're making are being applied to the phone view. may be it restrict due to media query.
5. Or you can check in incognito mode in your browser